# How do I get Apple TV 3rd Gen to connect to new Wi-Fi settings with no remote and a TV too far away for ethernet cable connection?

Tags: appletv, remote-control, remote.app

After a lightning strike I needed a new modem. Now I want to connect my existing Apple TV to my new Wi-Fi network.

My Apple remote is not paired as I always used an iPhone and iPad as my remote. The TV is too far away for an ethernet cable to reach the Apple TV box while HDMI is connected. I have a MacBook Air but it's never been connected to the Apple TV. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set the name (SSID) and password of the new network to be exactly the same as the old one, it's possible (I'm not positive, but it's worth a try) the Apple TV will connect automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Apple TV 3rd generation remotes actually use Infrared (IR) technology, so you should be able to just use the Apple Remote. The only reasons your remote may not work with the Apple TV are:

- A dead battery
- you have previously *linked* the remote to another device (e.g. a Mac)

So, if your Apple Remote is not working with your Apple TV you can replace the battery and/or link it to your Apple TV.

1. To replace the battery refer to [How to replace the battery in your Apple Remote](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201531). Once you've replaced the battery, if it doesn't work with your Apple TV, then try the next step.
2. To link the remote to your Apple TV you can just press and hold the Menu and Right buttons simultaneously for five seconds.

As an aside, you *may* also find that using the same SSID name and password for your new Wi-Fi network (as you did for your old one) means that your Apple TV will be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a smartphone with an integrated infrared port
2. Many smartphones have built-in remote control apps that allow you to communicate with many electronic devices (TV,receiver, etc..)
3. Use these apps to configure this smartphone into an Apple TV remote.
4. Once it's done, you can setup your wifi connection on your Apple TV.

Works fine for me. I have an LG G3.